# Fragment implementing AsyncTask and GridView in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I using Activity to load data from json with AsyncTask and display in Fragment class.
Display content include: ImageView, TextView, TextView and when user click an item will redirect corresponding item in GridView

In ManufactureFragment includes:

1. POJO ManufacturerItem
2. LoadAllManufacturers extends AsyncTask to load data from json
3. Adapter: call load data from json

My Fragment:

```
public class ManufacturerFragment extends Fragment {

ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


// initiliaze adapter variable
MyAdapter adapter; 
JSONArray manufacturers = null;

// manufacturers JSON url
private static final String URL_MANUFACTURERS = "http://MYURL";

public ManufacturerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_manufacturer, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    // gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), manufacturersList));
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), manufacturersList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // on selecting a single manufacturer
            // CategoryCarActivity will be launched to show category car inside the manufacturer
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CategoryCarActivity.class);

            // send manufacturer id to activity to get list of cars under that manufacturer
            String manufacturer_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("manufacturer_id", manufacturer_id);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    new LoadAllManufacturers().execute();
}


class LoadAllManufacturers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading manufacturers. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.manufacturersList = arrayList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (manufacturersList != null)
            return manufacturersList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        if (manufacturersList != null)
            return manufacturersList.get(i);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        if (manufacturersList != null)
            return manufacturersList.get(i).hashCode();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if(v == null)
        {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);   

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }
   }
 }
```

My list_item_manufacturers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Manufacturer_id / Hidden by default -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturer_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Manufacturer_name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturer_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Logo image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

My gridview_manufacturer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

When I debug and build, I see that json load success, but and then it happen a exception at line:
Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.totoroads.android.app, PID: 3723
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at com.totoroads.android.app.FeedBackFragment$LoadAllManufacturers.doInBackground(ManufacturerFragment.java:136)
                  at com.totoroads.android.app.FeedBackFragment$LoadAllManufacturers.doInBackground(ManufacturerFragment.java:89)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**final exception in Logcat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.totoroads.android.app, PID: 5730
              java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.totoroads.android.app.ManufacturerFragment$MyAdapter$ManufacturerItem
                  at com.totoroads.android.app.ManufacturerFragment$MyAdapter.getView(FeedBackFragment.java:226)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
```

at line:

```
ManufacturerFragment.MyAdapter.ManufacturerItem item = (ManufacturerFragment.MyAdapter.ManufacturerItem)getItem(i);
```

There are some wrong I can not detect it, How to fix this the exception

Thank you so much!!

Comment: if you are working with networking you should use retrofit+rxjava and for json parsing use GSON. for more info read this article https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/top-5-android-libraries-every-android-developer-should-know-about

Comment: in this article when i parse json I have used jersey and Gson. I have hear about Retrofit and try it later, because now I have to fix this below exception. thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize your `ArrayList` before calling your `AsyncTask`. Add this line before executing the `AsyncTask` in `onActivityCreated()` :

```
manufacturersList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Edit 1:**
Assign your adapter to the variable:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), manufacturersList);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Because now you are notifying an empty adapter with the changes.

**Edit 2:**
Your code never enters `onPostExecute` because you are not overriding the `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method. Your `AsyncTask` is initialized as `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`, therefore `onPostExecute`'s parameter should be a `String`, not a `Void`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

**Edit 3:**
This is a working example of your `getView` method that you can start with:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name, idTV;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
        picture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_name);
        idTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id);

        HashMap<String, String> itemHash = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(i);
        String nameString = itemHash.get(TAG_NAME);
        String iconUrl = itemHash.get(TAG_ICONNAME);
        String idString = itemHash.get(TAG_ID);

        // Use an image loader to load your Photo from URL.
        Picasso.with(context).load(iconUrl).into(picture);

        idTV.setText("ID: "+idString);
        name.setText("Name: "+nameString);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: I have added that line, it's seem no exception happened, but progress dialog is not stop: "loading manufacturer, please wait..."

Comment: Hi, I see that json has loaded by AsyncTask but can not display on screen

Comment: Hi MohanadMohie, I have updated your code, it's still same error

Comment: Please check Edit 2

Comment: Dear MohanadMohie, I have continue to update your step Edit 2, clean and rebuild project, when screen load data finish, screen is empty and blank now. Do you think property in my xml incorrect ?

Comment: I have added more 2 .xml file as above

Comment: This is not an XML problem, it's a Java code one. Remove `manufacturersList = new ArrayList<>();` from `onActivityCreated` since it is already initialized with its declaration in the new code, then the code will start working but you will get some exceptions inside `getView()` that you will need to solve to show your views.

Comment: As you said, there is an exception happened in getView() method. public View getView() return null, I have updated this exception above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126461/discussion-between-mohanadmohie-and-luongkhanh).

Answer (score 0):

I am writing only the changes in your code along with the lines above and below it.

Changes

1. Your `ArrayList` is `null`. Ininialize it.
2. Create a variable for adapter as you will need to call
   `notifyDataSetChanged` on it in `onPostExecute`.

```
// manufacturers JSON url
private static final String URL_MANUFACTURERS = "http://MYURL";

MyAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> manufacturersList = new ArrayList<>();

public ManufacturerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // initialize the adapter
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), manufacturersList)
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
}


class LoadAllManufacturers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        // notify the adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi K Neeraj Lal, I have refer your reply, it's good but it's same error. Progress dialog is not stop: "loading manufacturer, please wait..."

Comment: Logcart return json result: List of manufacturer, there is no exception. But data can not display on screen